# TCL Script Error Issue: [dim]GetAttrib: Missing current element

Tags: tcl

Problem with this script is that I can't get any info on the internet.

Can someone help to identify where is the issue?

This is a working script, but since last week, a new Account was added, and after that this script does not run properly anymore.

I manually added the newly added Account into my OLAP cube, and try to run the script agian, but to no avail.

What is GetAttrib: Missing current element?

```
#backup the OLAP and test&check FORECAST cleaning act. month and copy from FORECAST
###run transfer to Jan script !!!!
###manually backup MIS/R&D!!!! before because of changed IMD

#New Accounts & Update the Account name!
#OPEN ISSUES:   ORDERPOS
#               new parents 612x and 615x for exceptional accounts, if parents not already available (manually added/configured)

set sFilePath "d:\\PM10\\import Log files\\ACCOUNT_History.txt"
if {[file exists $sFilePath]==1} {
  set iFileID [open $sFilePath "a"]

  OLAP2 SelectDimension "ACCOUNT" dim

  RDB1 NewCursor "VIIPER.ACCOUNT" curs

  curs Open

  set iElement 0
  set iParent 0
  set iUpdateACCOUNT 0

  while {[curs Next]==1} {
   set sOrderpos "99999"
   if {[dim SelectElement $curs(ACCOUNT_ID)] == 0} {

     #1:ASSIGN
     set PL1 "6"
     set PL2 "7"
     if { [string compare [string range $curs(ACCOUNT_ID) 0 0] $PL1] == 0 || [string compare [string range $curs(ACCOUNT_ID) 0 0] $PL2] == 0} {
       set sAssign "1"
      } else {
       set sAssign "2"
     } 

     #Parent
     set sParent [string range $curs(ACCOUNT_ID) 0 2]

     #1:ORDERPOS
     set sElementOrderpos3 [string range $sParent 0 2]
     append sElementOrderpos3 "00000"

     set sElementOrderpos2 [string range $sParent 0 1]
     append sElementOrderpos2 "000000"

     set sElementBefore [expr $curs(ACCOUNT_ID) - 1]
     
     #backwards check to get the latest available account element to use the orderpos+1 - does not work for Orderpos! but needed for account check!!!!
     while {$sElementBefore >= $sElementOrderpos3} {
      if {[dim SelectElement $sElementBefore] == 1} {
       set sOrderpos [expr [dim GetAttrib "1:ORDERPOS"] + 1]
       break
      }
      set sElementBefore [expr $sElementBefore - 1] 
     }

   
     #parent "###" is needed/to be created, if not available
     if {([string compare $sElementOrderpos3 "612"] != 0 && [string compare $sElementOrderpos3 "615"] != 0)} {

      if {[string compare $sOrderpos "99999"] == 0} {
       puts "--> ISSUE in ACCOUNT: $curs(ACCOUNT_ID) - check if parents (XX/XXX) are available!"
###########################################################################################
###########################################################################################
#delete next lines  "###" after check    
###       if {$sElementBefore < $sElementOrderpos2} {
###        set sElementOrderpos2 [expr [string range $sParent 0 1] -1]
###        append sElementOrderpos2 "000000" 
###        while {$sElementBefore > $sElementOrderpos2} {
###         if {[dim SelectElement $sElementBefore] == 1} {
###          set sOrderpos [expr [dim GetAttrib "1:ORDERPOS"] + 1]
###        
###          dim NewNElement $sParent
###          dim PutAttrib "1:NAME" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
###          dim PutAttrib "2:ENGLISH" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
###          dim PutAttrib "2:GERMAN" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
###          dim PutAttrib "1:ASSIGN" $sAssign
###          set sNewCParent [string range $sParent 0 1]
###          dim PutAttrib "1:ORDERPOS" $sOrderpos
###          dim MemberOf $sNewCParent
###         
###          puts "Created New Parent: $sNewCParent, Account: $sElementOrderpos3 -->please check Element and Attributes"
###          fputs $iFileID "$act_date  NewParent   $sNewCParent    $sAssign    $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)"
###          
###          set sOrderpos [expr $sOrderpos + 1]
###          set iParent [expr $iParent + 1]
###          break
###         }
###         set sElementBefore [expr $sElementBefore - 1]
###        }
###########################################################################################
###########################################################################################
          }
       } else {
    
        while {$sElementBefore > $sElementOrderpos2} {
         if {[dim SelectElement $sElementBefore] == 1 && [dim SelectElement $sParent] == 0} {

          set sOrderpos [expr [dim GetAttrib "1:ORDERPOS"] + 1]
        
          dim NewNElement $sParent
          dim PutAttrib "1:NAME" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
          dim PutAttrib "2:ENGLISH" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
          dim PutAttrib "2:GERMAN" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
          dim PutAttrib "1:ASSIGN" $sAssign
          set sNewCParent [string range $sParent 0 1]
          dim PutAttrib "1:ORDERPOS" $sOrderpos
          dim MemberOf $sNewCParent

          puts "Created New Parent Account and Account: $sElementOrderpos3 -->please check Element and Attributes"
          fputs $iFileID "$act_date NewParent   $sNewCParent    $sParent    $sAssign    $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)"
          
          set iParent [expr $iParent + 1]
          set sOrderpos [expr $sOrderpos + 1]
          break
         }
         set sElementBefore [expr $sElementBefore - 1]
        }
      }  
      CloseDimension dim
      OLAP2 SelectDimension "ACCOUNT" dim
     }
 
     dim NewNElement $curs(ACCOUNT_ID)
     dim PutAttrib "1:NAME" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
     dim PutAttrib "2:ENGLISH" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
     dim PutAttrib "2:GERMAN" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
     dim PutAttrib "1:ORDERPOS" $sOrderpos
     dim PutAttrib "1:ASSIGN" $sAssign
     
     #exception in level logic XXXX instead of XXX AND Exception for 612x which is not 6120 then fix to 6122
     if {([string compare $sElementOrderpos3 "612"] == 0 || [string compare $sElementOrderpos3 "615"] == 0)} {
      "--> PARENT Exception for 612x or 615x"
      if {[string compare [string range $curs(ACCOUNT_ID) 0 3] "6120"] == 0 || [string compare $sElementOrderpos3 "615"] == 0} { 
        set sParent [string range $curs(ACCOUNT_ID) 0 3]
       } else {
        puts "--> PARENT exception fix to '6122'"
        set sParent "6122"
      } 
     } 
     
     dim MemberOf $sParent
     puts "New ACCOUNT: $curs(ACCOUNT_ID), Parent $sParent, $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME), Orderpos: $sOrderpos, Assign: $sAssign"
     fputs $iFileID "$act_date  NewAccount  $sParent    $curs(ACCOUNT_ID)   $sAssign    $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)"
     set iElement [expr $iElement + 1]
     CloseDimension dim
     OLAP2 SelectDimension "ACCOUNT" dim
    } else {
    
     #update name
     dim SelectElement $curs(ACCOUNT_ID)
     set oldACCOUNTname [dim GetAttrib "1:NAME"]
     set sOrderpos [dim GetAttrib "1:ORDERPOS"]
     if {[string compare $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME) $oldACCOUNTname] != 0} {
      dim PutAttrib "1:NAME" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
      dim PutAttrib "2:ENGLISH" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
      dim PutAttrib "2:GERMAN" $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME)
      #dim PutAttrib "1:ORDERPOS" $sOrderpos
      puts "Updated ACCOUNT: $curs(ACCOUNT_ID); new Name: $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME); old Name: $oldACCOUNTname"
      fputs $iFileID "$act_date Update  $curs(ACCOUNT_ID)   $curs(ACCOUNT_NAME) old: $oldACCOUNTname"
      set iUpdateACCOUNT [expr $iUpdateACCOUNT + 1]
     }
   }
  } 

  dim Sort -type CN -name ASC NOCASE -recursive 
  #-attrib "1:ORDERPOS" ASC NOCASE -recursive   

  DeleteCursor curs

  CloseDimension dim

 
  close $iFileID
 
 } else {
    puts "File do not exit"
}

puts "New ACCOUNT Parents #: $iParent"
puts "New ACCOUNT Elements #: $iElement"
puts "Updated ACCOUNT Elements #: $iUpdateACCOUNT"
```

this is the output is generated.

```
Import started at 18 Feb 2021 02:21:32.     
---------------------------------------------------     
Loading Script DLL     
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Cubeware\cwscript85.dll     
MMM-2020      
---------------------------------------------------     
ACCOUNT structure: Starting jobs at 18 Feb 2021 02:21:32     
Execute script: ACCOUNT structure - Started at 18 Feb 2021 02:21:32     
Driver 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Cubeware\cwiopmolap.dll' loaded. Version: 8.8.4.5     
OLAP2: Infor PM OLAP on mis/MIS connected.     
Driver 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Cubeware\cwiroledb.dll' loaded. Version: 8.8.4.3     
RDB1: OLE DB (OraOLEDB.Oracle): misdb user: melexis_pm connected.     
Error in script 'ACCOUNT structure', Line: 10     
[dim]GetAttrib: Missing current element.     
---------------------------------------------------        
Freeing resources     
Error in import        
Import finished at 18 Feb 2021 02:21:37
```

Comment: I can't tell where the problem is; the `GetAttrib` call is hidden somewhere. We need a proper traceback, and my answer should say how to get one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just *love* how that script is not printing where the problem was encountered! (Standard `tclsh` is *scrupulous* about printing error traces because it helps so much with tracking down problems.) Fortunately, we can add code to the script to make this much easier to track. Note that this is not really an answer, but rather information that might help you debug what's going wrong (but it's too long and structured for a comment).

Put this at the top:

```
package require Tcl 8.5
proc PrintTraceOnError {script} {
    set code [catch {uplevel 1 $script} msg opt]
    if {$code == 1} {
        puts "ERROR: $msg"
        puts "EXCEPTION CODE: [dict get $opt -errorcode]"
        puts "TRACEBACK: [dict get $opt -errorinfo]"
    }
    # Re-raise the error or send on the normal result
    return -options $opt $msg
}
```

Then wrap *the rest of your script* in `PrintTraceOnError {` and `}` to get better information about what actually went wrong. Hopefully that will be enough for you to figure out what information is missing or what schema change you have to adapt to.